# ORA-00936: missing expression distinct on oracle

Tags: sql, oracle10g, distinct

i am using oracle 10g plsql,
my query is:

```
select DISTINCT ON("Rental"."pkRentalId") "pkRentalId",
    to_number("Reservation"."ReservationNo") "ReservationNo",
    to_char("Rental"."RentalNo") "RentalNo",
    to_char(segmentTable."Text"||'-'||rateTypeTable."Text") "RateType",
    to_char("Debtor"."DebtorName") "DebtorName",
    to_char("Rates"."RateName") "RateName", 
    to_char("Renter"."FirstName"||' '||"Renter"."LastName") "Renter",
    to_date("Rates"."ValidFrom") "ValidFrom",
    to_date("Rates"."ValidTo") "ValidTo",
    round(to_number(to_number("ReservationDuration"."ExpectedCheckinDateTime"-"ReservationDuration"."DispatchDateTime") *to_number("Rates"."UnitRate")),2) "RentalAmount",
    to_number("Deductions"."Amount") "Deduction",
    to_number("Billing"."DiscountAmount") "Discount"
    from "Reservation" 
    inner join "Rental" on "Rental"."pkRentalId"="Reservation"."fkRentalId"
    inner join "Rates" on "Rates"."pkRateId"="Reservation"."fkRateId"
    inner join "Renter" on "Renter"."fkReservationId"="Reservation"."pkReservationId"
    inner join "Billing" on "Billing"."pkBillingId"="Reservation"."fkBillingId"
    inner join "Deductions" on "Deductions"."fkRentalId"="Rental"."pkRentalId"
    inner join "Debtor" on "Debtor"."pkDebtorId"="Rates"."fkDebtorId"
    inner join "EnumerationValue" segmentTable on segmentTable."pkEnumerationValueId"="Reservation"."fkSegmentId"
    inner join "EnumerationValue" rateTypeTable on rateTypeTable."pkEnumerationValueId"="Reservation"."fkRateTypeId"
    inner join "ReservationDuration" on "ReservationDuration"."pkDurationLocationId"="Reservation"."fkDurationId"
    where "Reservation"."IsDeleted"='N'
```

it is returning me :

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 17
```

What is the correct format of distinct on in oracle pl/sql?  I want to return all the distinct `"pkRentalId"` values and the maximum value for all the other columns.

Comment: If you want to use `DISTINCT`, you'd need to do a `DISTINCT` on every column in the select list.  I'm not sure what you want the `ON( "Rental"."pkRentalId")` clause to do but it's not valid syntax.

Comment: i only want to do the distinct clause on one of my selected columns. what do i have to do in this case? google search is recommending me the above syntax.
as you see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Comment: That is a link to PostgreSQL documentation, not Oracle.  If there are multiple rows in the result with the same `pkRentalId`, how do you know which of the other values you want to retain?

Comment: @Justin
you are right. exactly. what do i have to do in that case?

Comment: If there are multiple rows in the result set with the same `pkRentalId` value, how do you know which of the other values you want to retain?  Do you want the `min` value?  The `max` value?  Something else?

Comment: I want maximum value.

Comment: Oracle does not support Postgres' `distinct on` operator. The usual workaround is to use a window function (`row_number()`) to pick the unique rows based on a subset of the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the maximum value for each of the other columns, you'd need to do a `GROUP BY`, not a `DISTINCT` with the `max` aggregate function on all the other columns.

```
select "Rental"."pkRentalId",
    max(to_number("Reservation"."ReservationNo")) "ReservationNo",
    max(to_char("Rental"."RentalNo")) "RentalNo",
    max(to_char(segmentTable."Text"||'-'||rateTypeTable."Text")) "RateType",
    max(to_char("Debtor"."DebtorName")) "DebtorName",
    max(to_char("Rates"."RateName")) "RateName", 
    max(to_char("Renter"."FirstName"||' '||"Renter"."LastName")) "Renter",
    max(to_date("Rates"."ValidFrom")) "ValidFrom",
    max(to_date("Rates"."ValidTo")) "ValidTo",
    max(round(to_number(to_number("ReservationDuration"."ExpectedCheckinDateTime"-"ReservationDuration"."DispatchDateTime") *to_number("Rates"."UnitRate")),2)) "RentalAmount",
    max(to_number("Deductions"."Amount")) "Deduction",
    max(to_number("Billing"."DiscountAmount")) "Discount"
  from ...
 where ...
 group by "Rental"."pkRentalId"
```

Now, from a requirements standpoint, given the query you have, it seems unusual to want to get the maximum value for all the other columns.  That's going to mix data from multiple rows together in a way that doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Comment: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
the above query returns this to me

Comment: @KhurramZulfiqarAli - Are you sure that you added the aggregate function on every column in the query that you are not grouping by?

Answer (score 0):

The `distinct on` operator from Postgres usually translates to using the window function `row_number()` where the "distinct" columns are used for the `partition by` part and the `order by` is used to select the row you want:

```
select *
from (
  select 
      row_number() over partition by ("Rental"."pkRentalId" order by "Reservation"."ReservationNo") as rn, 
      ... other columns 
  from "Reservation" 
     ... joins 
  where "Reservation"."IsDeleted"='N' 
) 
where rn = 1
```

By changing the `order by` in the window definition you can pick which row you want ("first", "last", "third").

The difference to the solution using `max()` is that it will preserve the values that belong together in one row.